# adding clipart to an image with GIMP

Tags: gimp

I'm stuck with a task I initially thought should be very simple to complete. I would like to add some Christmassy clipart to a photo in GIMP and then print the photo or use it with an online card portal to send Christmas wishes. The reason I'm using GIMP is because it's truly free and Windows *Paint* can't seem to do on this. I'm open to suggestions to alternatives to GIMP for my purpose, yet am not happy to pay for an application for this.

When I save images from http://clipart-library.com/christmas-cliparts.html to my local drive and open them in GIMP via *File* --> *Open as Layers* I manage to change their locations in the overall image by using the handlers on the corners and in the centre of the clip-art. Yet whenever I want to move on to the next clipart image, the previous clipart blows up to the original size (i.e. in my case covering the original photo up completely).

Would appreciate any clear and concise instructions on how to add clipart images to a photo image. I haven't added a reproducible example hoping that the explanation is clear enough for someone experienced with GIMP. I've googled around for answers to my question, yet haven't found any answers yet. I'm not quite sure why GIMP makes this task so hard.

The reason I'm adding this post as I'm obviously not an expert in graphics, nor do I intend to be and need help. If I've added this post to the wrong group, please take this into consideration.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can a selection be upscaled in GIMP (without upscaling a layer or canvas)?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/150119/how-can-a-selection-be-upscaled-in-gimp-without-upscaling-a-layer-or-canvas)

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer to my question above. By choosing *Scale* in the context menu *Scale* that opens up with the image handlers, the clipart images stay in place.

[image]

Comment: When you move things around it's only a preview, you have to confirm your choice (this is true of other ops in Gimp, btw).

Comment: Also note that you can press [ENTER] to confirm scaling, or any other operation that requires confirming.